# Slow performance first queries on SQL Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have a very small database (50MB) and I'm on a basic plan.  There will be only a single user, but we need to create many databases (always one per user) since they will be used for training purposes.  Each database is created by doing the following statement:

```
CREATE DATABASE Training1 AS COPY OF ModelDatabase1
```

We seem to be getting very very slow performance when we first query this database, afterwards it seems acceptable.

To give you an idea: we have a SP: StartupEvents that runs when the application is started.  This query takes 25 seconds to run the first time.  This seems incredible since the database is very small, and the tables the query calls don't contain many records.  If we run this procedure afterwards it executes immediately...

How can we avoid this?

Comment: what is SP: StartupEvents

Comment: It's a stored procedure that does a couple of queries.

Comment: Has to read from disk.